# I am creating the integration flow for crating Shopify transaction to bank deposit in NetSuite using integrator.io?But i get following error message?

Tags: shopify, netsuite, integrator

I am creating the integration flow for importing Shopify transaction to bank deposit in NetSuite using celigo integrator.io?But i get following error message?

'Please enter value(s) for: Account'

but i already mapped account field in field mapping.Please find the attached images for that.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13QU3.png)

[Mapping Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOODk.png)

Comment: Issues like this are pretty common for Celigo products, sadly.  At my last company I was hired specifically to remove Celigo (which is not a simple task, since they dig their claws into everything).  Just my suggestion, move to a different iPaaS, as soon as you can.  The longer you wait, the harder it is to get rid of Celigo. ;)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, But it was client choice.so need help.

Comment: I would suggest contacting Celigo, then.  Since the issue is most likely caused by one of their scripts or workflows.

Comment: Are they using oneworld account? If yes, you might want to check if the account is available on the subsidiary of the transaction you are creating.

Comment: ok i will check that,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already resolved this. My 2 cents: this is typically a NetSuite user error. I'd suggest creating a Deposit via NetSuite and see if you encounter this error or perhaps update your mappings to use the field Account (InternalId) of Type HardCoded instead of Account (Name).

Comment: Hello Rohit. This is not an answer to the question. When you have enough reputation points, you will be able to leave comments on questions. What you have posted here would be an excellent comment. However, it is not a suitable answer.